# no module named zmq for python code

Tags: python, zeromq

When I try to run this script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

#
#   Hello World client in Python
#   Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
#   Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
#


import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print "Connecting to hello world server…"
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555")

#  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
for request in range (10):
    print "Sending request ", request,"…"
    socket.send ("Hello")

    #  Get the reply.
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received reply ", request, "[", message, "]"
```

When I do - python peer.py

I get `ImportError: No module named zmq`

But I already installed the python binding for zeromq using - easy_install pyzmq. 
How do I check if the binding is not installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try "python -v peer.py" - that should show the paths being searched for your module.  You can get a similar result with strace on Linux, but python -v is more targeted in this case.

Also consider the possibility that you have more than one Python on your system - if you're on a Linux with bash, "type -all python" may be informative.